# Как извлечь адрес гиперссылки из картинки в Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Есть проблема - как извлечь адрес гиперссылки из картинки в Excel? Есть прайс с картинками, которые представлены в виде гиперссылок. Как просто извлечь адрес из гиперссылки в ячейке я нашел 3 макроса, но  с картинками они не работают ((( Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать?

Comment: Прайс с картинками в каком формате? Тоже Excel? Приведите скрины.

Comment: @TilekSamiev Да, exel, если точнее то .xlsm

Comment: @TilekSamiev ![скрин](https://radikal.ru/big/kmr62afu2cepl)

Comment: http://howtouseexcel.net/how-to-extract-a-url-from-a-hyperlinked-image-graphic-or-icon-on-excel

вот тут есть макрос, который извлекает гиперссылку из картинки